# Going to the rootViewController of another navigationController programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have an iPhone app with a UITabBar, and each tab has a unique navigationController.

I'm adding a UIBarButton the navigationBar of each tab that will take the end user to the rootViewController of the first tab's navigationController.

I'm trying to figure out how to do this.  So far I have this:

```
- (void)navBarButtonPressed:(UIButton *)button {
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Which works for switching to the first tab.  But from there, how do I go to the root view controller of the first tab's navigationController?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can pop to root view controller as

```
[(UINavigationController *)self.tabBarController.selectedViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```